# Two-dimensional random progression in R

Tags: r

It's my first question in StackOverflow and I hope it's the first of many. My doubt is about an especific function that I'm trying to do in R, the programming language that I'm learning this year. The function consists of doing a two-dimensional random progression defined in this way:

- For t = 1, the progression is (a1,a2).
- At each subsequent moment, the position is calculated by applying the
  next rule:

  - With a probability of 5%, x_n=x_{n-1}+1 and y_n=y_{n-1}-1
  - With a probability of 15%, x_n=2x_{n-1} and y_n=y_{n-1}+1
  - With a probability of 80%, x_n=x_{n-1}+1 and y_n=2y_{n-1}

What I've done is using sample function with two progressions, because I've tried to adapt it to one with no exit. I'd like to use probabilities in a tuple, not in a separately way. Could you help me with this? I'd thank you.

```
         simulate <- function(n,a1,a2){
             x <- a1
             y <- a2

             for(t in 2:n){
               print(paste("(",x,",",y,")"))
               x <- sample(c(x+1,2*x,x+1),size=1,prob=c(0.05,0.15,0.8))
               y <- sample(c(y-1,y+1,2*y),size=1,prob=c(0.05,0.15,0.8))
               }

             print(paste("Final tuple is: (",x,",",y,")"))
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't appear to follow the description you've given. You describe three outcomes, but the function allows for nine.
My first instinct was to do something like this. Is the `z` vector here what you allude to with "probabilities in a tuple"?

```
sim <- function(n, a1, a2) {

    x <- vector(length=n)
    y <- vector(length=n)

    x[1] <- a1
    y[1] <- a2

    z <- sample(1:100, n, replace=TRUE)

    for (i in 2:n) {
        if (z[i] <= 5) {
            x[i] <- x[i-1] + 1
            y[i] <- y[i-1] - 1
            next
        }
        if (z[i] <= 20) {
            x[i] <- x[i-1] * 2
            y[i] <- y[i-1] + 1
            next
        } 
        x[i] <- x[i-1] + 1
        y[i] <- y[i-1] * 2
    }
    cbind(x, y, z)
}

set.seed(9)
sim(6, 20, 10)
#       x   y  z
# [1,] 20  10 23
# [2,] 21   9  3
# [3,] 22  18 21
# [4,] 23  36 22
# [5,] 24  72 45
# [6,] 48  73 14
```

Comment: Hi! Thank for the answer. I know what I've done it's not exactly what I described. I'm basically doing like two progressions but I don't know how to put one single sample for a one single progression in a tuple form, not x first and then y. Your post is probably what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you call it a tuple you'll probably confuse most R people. In R it'd be called a vector.